# How do you keep the Enter key events from bubbling up to a control after a msgbox displays (eg. the message box OK button - Enter)?

Tags: c#

I know I've run into this before, but I can't remember the fix -

I have a textbox which acts as a search once the user hits the enter key. I use the TextBox KeyPress and KeyUp events to check for the Enter key.

If the text is NOT found, a message box pops up saying "Not found"

If the user then hits the enter key to CLOSE the message box, the TextBox key events fire again and the message box keeps popping up. If they use the mouse to click on the button, the message box goes away successfully.

I know I could just create my own MessageBox form, but is there a simple way to stop this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: This is because of the KeyUp event. If you use only the KeyPress Event, you will not see the issue

Comment: Moving the code out of the KeyUp event solved the problem thanks!

Comment: Hmm...this doesn't seem to work for an Input Box though - I have a button on a form that calls the Input box and it keeps firing the Button click event...